# SQL Server trigger for verifying date column doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, triggers

I have a table for scheduled surgeries and I am trying to write a trigger that will print a message in case the user inserts a past date in the date column (in the logic that you can not schedule something in the past).

What I wrote won't do anything, so if you can please take a look and give me some advice on how I should write it.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TR_verifyProg') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER TR_verifyProg
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_verifyProg
ON Interventii
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT Interventii.[Data] 
         FROM Interventii) < GETDATE())
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Data interventiei trebuie sa fie minim cea curenta';
    END
END
```

Comment: Where do you expect to see the result of the print statement? Where are you calling the insert from? You probably want to throw an error and handle that in your code. Also I suspect you want an after trigger not an instead of trigger.

Comment: Why don't you use a [CHECK Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#Check)?

Comment: Aside... it's an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, meaning that it gets executed instead of actually inserting data in the target table. It's up to the trigger to use the `INSERTED` virtual table to perform any validation and then insert those rows in the table/s in which it needs to reside.

Comment: I would strongly suggest not doing this. Not being able to insert correct data retrospectively without change control getting involved (for them to temporarily disable the trigger, for example) makes a miserable experience for both the users and tech support. Warn the user, yes. Maybe even flag up (be separately recording when the row was inserted) that it's happening so that actual misuse can be tracked. But please don't prevent people getting on with their jobs.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answers. I changed the if statement by declaring two variables before it and using them in the if clause and now it works.

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TR_verifyProg
ON Interventii
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @data date =(SELECT [Data] FROM inserted)
DECLARE @today date =GETDATE()
IF (@data<@today)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Data interventiei trebuie sa fie minim cea curenta!';
    END
END
```

Comment: That only works if there is exactly 1 row in Inserted. However Inserted can have 0-N rows, in which case your trigger breaks. Also nothing ever gets inserted when Yiu have an instead of trigger without an insert.

Comment: No no no no no! You should not use PRINT in a trigger in a production system for anything. You let the caller know of errors by THROWing them. And you failed to understand the significant difference between an AFTER trigger and an INSTEAD OF trigger. And there's the multi-row problem as well. In addition, a trigger can execute if NO ROWS are inserted - you need to handle that situation as well.